# Flutter CustomPainter How to trigger a repaint

Tags: flutter

I'm working on an app that uses CustomPainter and that repaints when a build is performed. This build instantiates a new instance of the CustomPainter that repaints the canvas. This works OK, however I believe it is possible to trigger a repaint on an instance of CustomPainter directly with having to reinstantiate it in a build. Can someone point me to an example that shows how that is done?

Comment: Have you tried writing your own `RenderObject`? It sounds like `CustomPainter` is not what you want to be using.

Comment: see `repaint` property

Comment: oops, it's `repaint` parameter in the constructor

Comment: Thanks for that. shouldRepaint does not fire :).